# What is Z tensor 0? What about Z tortion 0?

Tags: homology-cohomology, tensor-products, group-cohomology

What is Z tensor 0?

I believe it is also 0, what is it?
[image: attached is a homework problem I am working on]

Comment: What exactly is the relevance of that picture to your question?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have a couple of tensor products where I am tensoring 0 but we were never told what it actually was.

Comment: I feel like you should look up the definition of these things and you'll understand.

Answer (score 3):

Anything tensor zero is zero by the bilinearity of the tensor product.

$$a\otimes 0= a\cdot0 \otimes1= 0(a\otimes1).$$

Comment: Thank you! What about torsion?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? By torsion? Also, if that was satisfactory you can select it as an accepted answer

Comment: @user338365 what did you mean by torsion?